# Getting detailed data from json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file like this

```
{
    "doctors": [{
        "name": "...",
        "Section": "...",
        "Grade": "..."
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "Section": "...",
        "Grade": "..."
    }],
    "nurses": [{
        "name": "...",
        "Grade": "..."
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "Grade": "..."
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "Grade": "..."
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "Grade": "..."
    }]
}
```

Inside the script tag of the html file I have defined a loadData function that is called when a button is pressed.

```
function loadStaffData() {
        var xo = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xo.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xo.open('GET', 'staff_data.json', true); 
        xo.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xo.readyState == 4 && xo.status == "200") {                  

              var X=JSON.parse(xo.responseText);
              console.log(X); //line 18
            }
          };
          xo.send(null);
        }
```

Right now I am only able to get the whole set of data in the json file. But I need to be ale to retrieve each doctor's/ nurse's name/ section/ gender separately. I tried typing  `xo.responseText('doctors'[0])` and even `xo.responseText([0][0])`, but none of them worked.

**Edit**
I have also tried parsing the responseText: `JSON.parse(xo.responseText)`. But I have got this error: `JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 18`

The json file is on my local disc and I use firefox (developer edition) to get output.

Comment: The `responseText` is text. Parse it into an object before trying to access it like an object.

Comment: After you parse it, it's `data.doctors[i]` and `data.nurses[i]`

Comment: Please see the edit I made to the main question.

Comment: @MaYaNicolson I just have checked your JSON file content in your question. The structure is correct so `JSON.parse` should be executed without problems. Can you display the results of `xo.responseText` ? (simply do `console.log(xo.responseText)` and c/p over the output)

Comment: I have solved the problem. There were soecial characters in the fields that had to be taken care of. 
I am not able to post my answer, becausse the question is marked and closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

try:

JSON.parse(xo.responseText)["doctors"][0]

You need to parse the request response, then you can select the data.

Comment: I tried it and got this error
 `JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value`

Comment: humm, Are you sure your json is vaild?

Comment: Yes I am sure about it.

Comment: Update: you were right. I had to fix the json file.